# Trabalhando com botões BACK da Navigation Bar(nativo do smartphone) e Action Bar(adicionado via Java)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Estou Fazendo esta pergunta/resposta para ajudar quem talvez teve/tem/tenha alguma duvida referente aos botões **BACK** que são extremamente úteis em nossos aplicativos.
Utilizarei **1** e **2** para diferenciar ***Action Bar* (1)** e ***Navigation Bar* (2)**
[image: Action e Navigation - BAR]

Agradeço muito aos usuários daqui mesmo do Stack que me ajudaram a encontrar esta solução que foram: **Jean Felipe D. Silva** e **Regmoraes**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1. Back - Action Bar**

- Dentro do método `onCreate(){` adicione as seguintes linhas:

  ```
  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); //Mostrar o botão
  getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);      //Ativar o botão
  getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Seu titulo aqui");     //Titulo para ser exibido na sua Action Bar em frente à seta
  ```
- Fora do método `oncreate(){}` adicione:

  ```
  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { //Botão adicional na ToolBar
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case android.R.id.home:  //ID do seu botão (gerado automaticamente pelo android, usando como está, deve funcionar
          startActivity(new Intent(this, SuaActivity.class));  //O efeito ao ser pressionado do botão (no caso abre a activity)
          finishAffinity();  //Método para matar a activity e não deixa-lá indexada na pilhagem
          break;
      default:break;
  }
  return true;
  }
  ```

Tudo pronto, seu botão *Action Bar* está funcionando!

**2. Back - Navigation Bar**

- Fora do método `onCreate(){}`

  ```
  @Override
  public void onBackPressed(){ //Botão BACK padrão do android
  startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class)); //O efeito ao ser pressionado do botão (no caso abre a activity)
  finishAffinity(); //Método para matar a activity e não deixa-lá indexada na pilhagem
  return;
  }
  ```

Tudo deve estar funcionando perfeitamente agora

Answer (score 0):

Você pode resolver isso no manifest adicionando esse atributo na activity atual

```
android:parentActivityName=".activity.PrincipalActivity"
```

Answer (score 0):

Complementando a resposta do Erasmo, além de adicionar o atributo `parentActivityName`, adicione também o atributo `launchMode` no bloco que se destina a tela principal. Irei colocar um código abaixo descrevendo melhor minha resposta.

Onde o `manisfest` da sua aplicação ficara assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.exemplo.ExemploDeCodigo">


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

        <activity
            android:name=".SegundaActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Sendo que, toda vez que uma nova activity for adicionada no seu projeto, você adiciona o `parentActivityName` apontando para a activity que você deseja que volte.

Outro ponto interessante é que se você não desejar perder algum dado de uma tela e quiser que ela se mantenha igual ao passar para a tela seguinte e depois retornar, basta usar o `android:launchMode="singleTop"`, isso fará que os dados sejam mantidos.